# Timeout expired Max,max pool size was reached

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis

I get this exception on WCF service level.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the
>   pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in
>   use and max pool size was reached

Currently there are two instance are used in IIS 7.

I also max pool size max on SQL server 2012 level
Select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS Reuslt is 32767.

I can't understand why this exception came. (The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.)

Comment: Do you Close/Dispose all connections properly? What code are you running?

Comment: that application also   run on production server  without any exception.